# Synonyms or Aliases Won't Allow Us To Schema Bind or Index a View

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have four measure amounts within the same view definition with each referring to the same measure description lookup table. Our problem is that we want to schema bind and index this view. We have tried using aliases as well as synonyms for the repeated joins to the lookup table. We are still unable to place the index on the view because these are "self-joins" or because synonyms are invalid in a schemabound object or a constraint expression. Any help or advice is appreciated.

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[VPLAN_SEG_SYNtst] WITH SCHEMA BINDING 
AS 
SELECT DBO.PLAN_SEG.PLAN_SEG_ID, DBO.PLAN_SEG.PLAN_SEG_DESC, 
    DBO.PLAN_SEG.PLAN_ITEM_ID, DBO.SEG_SL_MEAS.SL_MEAS_DESC, 
    DBO.SEG_EST_SL_MEAS.SL_MEAS_DESC AS EST_SL_MEAS_DESC 
FROM DBO.PLAN_SEG 
INNER JOIN DBO.SEG_SL_MEAS 
   ON DBO.PLAN_SEG.CLIENT_ID = DBO.SEG_SL_MEAS.CLIENT_ID 
   AND DBO.PLAN_SEG.SEG_SL_MEAS_SYS_ID = DBO.SEG_SL_MEAS.SL_MEAS_SYS_ID 
INNER JOIN DBO.SEG_EST_SL_MEAS 
   ON DBO.PLAN_SEG.SEG_EST_SL_MEAS_SYS_ID = DBO.SEG_EST_SL_MEAS.SL_MEAS_SYS_ID 
   AND DBO.PLAN_SEG.CLIENT_ID = DBO.SEG_EST_SL_MEAS.CLIENT_ID 
GO
```

Error:

```
ERROR Msg 2788, Level 16, State 1, Procedure VPLAN_SEG_SYNtst, Line 5 
    Synonyms are invalid in a schemabound object or a constraint expression.

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_PLAN_SET_TST 
    ON VPLAN_SEG_TST (PLAN_SEG_ID) 
ERROR Msg 1947, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot create index on view 
    "SLHUB.dbo.VPLAN_SEG_TST". The view contains a self join on "SLHUB.dbo.ZSL_MEAS".
```

Comment: ALTER VIEW [dbo].[VPLAN_SEG_SYNtst]
WITH SCHEMA BINDING
AS
SELECT DBO.PLAN_SEG.PLAN_SEG_ID, DBO.PLAN_SEG.PLAN_SEG_DESC, DBO.PLAN_SEG.PLAN_ITEM_ID, DBO.SEG_SL_MEAS.SL_MEAS_DESC,
DBO.SEG_EST_SL_MEAS.SL_MEAS_DESC AS EST_SL_MEAS_DESC
FROM DBO.PLAN_SEG INNER JOIN DBO.SEG_SL_MEAS ON DBO.PLAN_SEG.CLIENT_ID = DBO.SEG_SL_MEAS.CLIENT_ID AND DBO.PLAN_SEG.SEG_SL_MEAS_SYS_ID = DBO.SEG_SL_MEAS.SL_MEAS_SYS_ID INNER JOIN DBO.SEG_EST_SL_MEAS ON DBO.PLAN_SEG.SEG_EST_SL_MEAS_SYS_ID = DBO.SEG_EST_SL_MEAS.SL_MEAS_SYS_ID AND DBO.PLAN_SEG.CLIENT_ID = DBO.SEG_EST_SL_MEAS.CLIENT_ID
 
GO

Comment: ERROR
Msg 2788, Level 16, State 1, Procedure VPLAN_SEG_SYNtst, Line 5
Synonyms are invalid in a schemabound object or a constraint expression.

Comment: CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_PLAN_SET_TST ON VPLAN_SEG_TST (PLAN_SEG_ID)
 
ERROR
Msg 1947, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot create index on view "SLHUB.dbo.VPLAN_SEG_TST". The view contains a self join on "SLHUB.dbo.ZSL_MEAS".

Comment: Indexed view are nice. Unfortunately in real life there are not as many scenarios where you can actually use them as one would like. In an answer below there is a link to requirements for a view to be allowed to be indexed. I rarely see a view in the wild that I want to index that would ever fulfil these requirements. Sad but true.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to index this view? It doesn't have a lot of the other things you expect to find in an indexed view (e.g. an aggregate like `COUNT`). I've implemented plenty of indexed views in my day (don't believe @zespri that they don't exist or are useless in the real world) but I fail to see the purpose of one that has self-joins and/or points to synonyms. Can you explain your actual goal, rather than the fact that you want to index this view?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: never said they are useless

Comment: @zespri I know. I was paraphrasing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to place an index on a view, it must be schemabound.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx for other requirements.